# Можно ли таким образом возвращать локальный указатель из функции?

Tags: c++, функции, указатели

В книге С. Прата наткнулся на пример:

```
struct free_throws {
     int made;
     int attempts;
     double percent;
};
const free_throws & clone(free_throws &ft) {
     free_throws *pt;
     pt = &ft;
     return *pt;
}
```

Насколько я понимаю нельзя возвращать локальные переменные по ссылке или по адресу, потому что они уничтожатся по окончанию функции и вернется ссылка на уже несуществующую переменную, т.е. на "мусор".
**Вопрос:** можно ли так возвращать локальную переменную-указатель? Почему?

Comment: Здесь не возвращается локальный указатель. Здесь ссылка, на некоторый нелокальный объект, ссылка на который была передана в качестве аргумента.

Comment: сдесь важно понимать различие: вы возвращаете указатель не на локальную переменную, на указатель на переменную, которая была передана по ссылке в функцию. Эта переменная существует и за пределами вызова этой функции, так что никакой проблемы сдесь нет

Comment: Внутренняя переменная имеет тип `free_throws *`. Её по ссылке передавать нельзя как `free_throws * &`. Вы же передаёте ссылку на совсем другой объект.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Давайте посмотрим, что у вас получается...

```
const free_throws & clone(free_throws &ft) {
```

Вы передаете функции ссылку на lvalue - на некий объект за пределами функции.

```
     free_throws *pt;
     pt = &ft;
     return *pt;
```

И по сути возвращаете его. Т.е. можно было просто написать -

```
     return ft;
```

Т.е. вы вернули ссылку на тот же объект, который и передали, только как на константный. Так что возвращать-то можно, а смысл?

Я тут - https://ideone.com/5fSQqc - немного упростил в смысле типов, и убрал константность - как видите, `clone()` возвращает просто то, что ей передали. Скажем так - никакого клонирования при этом не происходит.

Вот если бы вы сделали так:

```
const free_throws & clone(free_throws ft) {
```

это уже был бы возврат ссылки на локальную переменную (переданную в функцию копию) - тут дело другое.

Comment: Ну, а теперь, кто минус поставил - подскажите, в чем именно я неправ? Я могу и ошибаться, но чтоб я не ошибался в другой раз - покажите, где ошибка?